# Loading animations with buttons in android

Tags: android, animation, button

I have an activity in android which I set up a button under a `SurfaceView`. And the result looks like this:
[image]

And I'm satisfied with it except one thing, the writing on the button is astray and must be setup correctly.
For this I used animations like this:

```
takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto);
takePhoto.setText(t);

RotateAnimation ranim = (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanim);
ranim.setFillAfter(true);
takePhoto.setAnimation(ranim);
```

WHERE the `res/anim/myanim` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromDegrees="0" 
       android:toDegrees="-90"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="0" />
```

But the result is a little bit disappointing cause the whole looks like:

[image]

The text is ok, but the dimensions are reduced.

What I want is to keep the text correctly and the initial size.How could I do that???
It has nothing to do with the button's properties in the xml file cause I haven't changed them when loading the animation....Ideas?Thanks...

EDIT: `xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<SurfaceView android:layout_width="450dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/surface_camera" />

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/surface_camera"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<Button android:layout_width="680dip"
android:layout_height="680dip" 
android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:text="Take Photo" 
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>





IMPORTANT:

In the cases described below...my activity is in `LANDSCAPE` mode and the position of the phone is portrait.Another issue is that when I turn my phone in landscape mode(and here I mean the position of the phone, cause the activity is still landscape) the button doesn't go at the bottom of the phone is stays there.No matter how I turn the phone the button is in the same position!!!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Make two layout folders like follows ...

[image]

In both of folders your layout file name should be same.

In `layout-port` folder your layout file should look like this ...

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/surface_camera"
```

replaced by ...

```
android:layout_Below="@id/surface_camera"
```

as follows ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<SurfaceView android:layout_width="450dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/surface_camera" />

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_toBelow="@id/surface_camera" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<Button android:layout_width="680dip"
android:layout_height="680dip" 
android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:text="Take Photo" 
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Even this will considered as bad practice but you can also handle this manually, try this  ..

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //setContentView(R.layout.main);

      int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

      if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
         setContentView(R.layout.main1);

      }
      else {

         setContentView(R.layout.main2);
      }
   }
```

Also If you are doing this way No need to make two layout folders, but needs two layout files main1 and main2 in same folder

Yet another option ...

In manifest ...

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

+

In your Activity ...

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

      int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
      if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
      }
      else {

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this XML instead:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <SurfaceView    android:id="@+id/surface_camera" 
                    android:layout_width="450dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <FrameLayout    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/surface_camera"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <TextView   android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:text="Take Photo" />
    </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

You will rotate the Text not the button.